# htaccess не срабатывает правило

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=yml/sitemap [L]
```

Подскажите почему не работает это правило? Ну то есть если в url вставить sitemap.xml - перенаправляет на страницу 404, а если index.. то все норм!
Что делаю не так? Вот полный код:

```
    ErrorDocument 400 /not-found/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^rewrite_url$ index.php?route=module/url [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=yml/sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap-product.xml$ index.php?route=yml/sitemap_product [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap-tags.xml$ index.php?route=yml/sitemap_tags [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap-category.xml$ index.php?route=yml/sitemap_category [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap-blog.xml$ index.php?route=yml/sitemap_blog [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap-filter.xml$ index.php?route=yml/sitemap_filter [L]
RewriteRule \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|jpeg)$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[^A-Z]*[A-Z].*
RewriteRule ^ ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.tricolor.com.ua$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://tricolor.com.ua/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^185.65.247.147$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://tricolor.com.ua/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^market.tricolor.com.ua$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://tricolor.com.ua/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^assets.tricolor.com.ua$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://tricolor.com.ua/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.tricolor.com.ua$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://tricolor.com.ua/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=common/home$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://tricolor.com.ua? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^stopexit/show$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://tricolor.com.ua/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.tricolor.com.ua
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://tricolor.com.ua/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image1.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image2.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image3.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image4.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image5.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image6.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image7.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image8.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image9.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image10.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image11.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image12.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image13.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image14.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image15.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image16.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image17.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image18.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image19.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^image20.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^js.tricolor.com.ua$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ subdomain-robots.txt


<ifModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    #по умолчанию кеш в 5 секунд
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
    #кэшировать изображения на месяц
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 604800 seconds"
    #кэшировать css, javascript и текстовые файлы на одну неделю
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
    #кэшировать html и htm файлы на один день
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 43200 seconds"
    #кэшировать xml файлы на десять минут
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico|xml)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

FileETag MTime Size
```

Comment: в админке чпу включили?

Comment: нет............